# How to disable AjaxLink button in wicket?

Tags: wicket

I'm trying to disable an `AjaxLink` button in wicket inside the
`public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target)` method;
I tried calling the `setEnabled(false)` directly but didn't work. some of the suggestions I saw online says call the `isEnabled() or onConfigure()` methods; but these cannot be implemented inside the `onclick` method; any help please?

```
            {
                buttonlabel.setDefaultModel(Model.of("Creating EWL"));
                target.add(buttonlabel);
                buttonlabel.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);

                boolean isWorkItemCreated = NewRecruitEWLUtil.createNewRecruitWorkItem(appInfo);

                if (isWorkItemCreated)
                {
                    buttonlabel.setDefaultModel(Model.of("EWL Created"));
                    target.add(buttonlabel);
                    buttonlabel.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);
                    setEnabled(false);
                    target.add(this);
                    System.out.println("setEnabled ..." + isEnabled());
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

`setEnabled(false)` is the correct way! You also need to add the AjaxLink to the AjaxRequestTarget so it is repaint at the browser:

```
AjaxLink link = new AjaxLink("myLink") {
    @Override
    public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
       setEnabled(false);
       target.add(this);
    }
};
add(link);
link.setOutputMarkupId(true);
```

Comment: Thanks Martin, that fixed it.

Comment: Please accept the answer. Click on the check sign on the left.